# JQuery UI tabs get previously selected tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to select the previously active tab  when i click the new tab .How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#edit_tabs').tabs(  {
        selected: 2,     // which tab to start on when page loads
        select: function(e, ui) {
            var t = $(e.target);
            alert( "selected is " + t.data('selected.tabs') )
            // Index of the PREVIOUSLY selected tab 
            return true;

        }
});
```