# jQuery tabs - Get the index of previously selected tab

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.7.1 - I would like to get the index of previously selected tab. Ex: If I move to the 3rd tab from 1st, i would like to get the previous selected tab index as 0. How to achieve this?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664658/jquery-ui-tabs-get-previously-selected-tab), but that didn't work.

I have the following markup,

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="t1" title="content">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="t2" title="content">Polls</a></li>
      <li><a href="t3" title="content">Events</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript,

```
$('#tabs').tabs(  {
    select: function(e, ui) {
    var t = $(e.target);
    alert( "Index " + t.data('selected.tabs') );
    return true;
}});
```

Comment: Show some code. Markup and javascript preferably. An http://jsfiddle.net sample illustrating the problem would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the select or show callbacks fire you can only get the currently selected tag, by using `ui.index`. Your best bet is to just track that index and update it upon tab switching, which will tell you the previous index before said updating.

```
var previousIndex = 0;
$('#tabs').tabs(  {
    select: function(e, ui) {
        //do whatever you need to do with previousIndex
        alert("The previously selected tab index was " + previousIndex);
        //track the new index
        previousIndex = ui.index;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Parrots. I followed your advice and it works. I have one more problem, when I load the page, by default I open a tab. So I have the following code,     $tabs.tabs('select', <c:out value="${param.index}" />);  ,  but this doesn't fire the select callback function. I found a workaround by assigning 'previousIndex' with the index value from the query string. Is there any other way to fire the callback function?

Comment: Not sure, I would have assumed it would call the callback. Worst case I think your workaround makes sense.

Comment: The following code also works,    var previousIndex = 0;
 $('#tabs').tabs(  {
  select: function(e, ui) {
   var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    previousIndex = selected;
        }
 });   Anyone has any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
    `$(this).tabs('option', 'selected')`
in select: option

like

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
      select: function(event, ui){
          console.log($(this).tabs('option', 'selected')}
      )}
});
```